# Image URL from RSS

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

I have an app that shows an RSS feed. I am able to get the item titles, dates, and links with no problems but I am trying to figure out how to get the thumbnail URL.

EDIT: I am getting URLs, but my array of URL strings is filled with only the first URL. It is just storing it 22 times in the array.

Here is the XML from the feed with the image URL:

```
<media:thumbnail xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" url="http://kyfbnewsroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Beltway-News-web-250x250.jpg" width="250" height="250"/>
```

Here is my code:

```
public void getDataFromFeed(){

        try {
            Feed = new URL(URLFeed);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(new InputSource(Feed.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            title = new String[nodeList.getLength()];
            pubDate = new String[nodeList.getLength()];
            link = new String[nodeList.getLength()];
            thumb = new String[nodeList.getLength()];

            for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength();i++){
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

                NodeList titleList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("title");
                Element titleElement = (Element) titleList.item(0);
                titleList = titleElement.getChildNodes();
                title[i] = ((Node) titleList.item(0)).getNodeValue();

                NodeList pubDateList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("pubDate");
                Element pubDateElement = (Element) pubDateList.item(0);
                pubDateList = pubDateElement.getChildNodes();
                pubDate[i] = ((Node) pubDateList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                // chops off the " +0000" on date
                pubDate[i] = pubDate[i].substring(0, pubDate[i].length()-14);

                NodeList thumbList = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("media:thumbnail");
                Element thumbElement = (Element)thumbList.item(0);
                String thumbURL = thumbElement.getAttribute("url");
                thumb[i] = thumbURL;

                NodeList linkList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("link");
                Element linkElement = (Element) linkList.item(0);
                linkList = linkElement.getChildNodes();
                link[i] = ((Node) linkList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using org.w3c.dom do this:

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("media", "thumbnail");
// if you expect there to possibly be more than one use a loop or whatever
Element elm = (Element) nodes.item(0); 
String url = elm.getAttribute("url");
```

Comment: See my update. I've added this but the String url causes it to crash.

Comment: I fixed that issue. I just had to change ("media", "thumbnail") to ("media:thumbnail")

Comment: I'm getting 22 objects in my URL array but they are all null.

Comment: Never mind. I should have been adding the thumbURL string to my array. I'm getting the URLs now.

Comment: I just noticed that my array of URLs is filled with the same URL for each index. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: what does the document look like? getElementsByTagName or getElementsByTagNameNS should return all the elements with the tag name. hence the method name tee hee!